# Python need help in removing leading and trailing whitespace within string inside bracket in xpath

Tags: python, regex

I have some xpath strings in which I need help in removing one or more leading and trailing whitespace within string inside bracket. So, these are some sample xpaths I have:

```
'/a/b[b1=" a12s "]/c[c1="1a3 "]/d'
'/a/b[b1=" 12a6a"]/c[c1="  s23 "]/d'
'/a/b[b1="s9d  "]/c[c1=" 1 2 x "]/d'
```

And this is the output I am looking for:

```
'/a/b[b1="a12s"]/c[c1="1a3"]/d'
'/a/b[b1="12a6a"]/c[c1="s23"]/d'
'/a/b[b1="s9d"]/c[c1="1 2 x"]/d'
```

I need help in removing these one or more leading and trailing whitespaces from xpaths. Kindly guide me on this.

Comment: You could substitute matches of `(?<=[\"']) *| *(?=[\"'])` with empty strings. This removes spaces that follow or precede double or single quotes. (This responds to your comment below that you want to include single quotes as well as double quotes.) `(?<=[\"'])`is a positive lookbehind; `(?=[\"'])` is a positive lookahead. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p43d3O/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zMAE23/1)):

```py
import re

s = """\
'/a/b[b1=" a12s "]/c[c1="1a3 "]/d'
'/a/b[b1=" 12a6a"]/c[c1="  s23 "]/d'
'/a/b[b1="s9d  "]/c[c1=" 1 2 x "]/d'"""

s = re.sub(r"\"\s*(.*?)\s*\"", r'"\g<1>"', s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
'/a/b[b1="a12s"]/c[c1="1a3"]/d'
'/a/b[b1="12a6a"]/c[c1="s23"]/d'
'/a/b[b1="s9d"]/c[c1="1 2 x"]/d'
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle both single and double quotes, If I replace single quotes with double and vice versa?

Comment: @TonyMontana Do you mean `s = re.sub(r"'\s*(.*?)\s*'", r"'\g<1>'", s)` ?

Comment: No, I meant, what if the xpath outer string is covered by double quotes and inside the bracket it is covered by single quote?

Comment: No, need of. I just tweaked your regex and came up with this https://regex101.com/r/wh8yHV/1. Thanks BTW!